# How do you change HTTPS proxy settings with networksetup?

Tags: osx, networksetup

To set it for HTTP, I do this:

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-Fi" 127.0.0.1 9595
```

But I want to know how to set it up for HTTPS as well. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-setsecurewebproxy`, for example:

```
networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-Fi" 127.0.0.1 9595
```

And to turn it off/on:

```
networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "Wi-Fi" off

networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "Wi-Fi" on
```